# Code behind works but MVVM doesnt

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I have been messing with something that works in the code behind but when I try and bind to a MVVM , nothing displays. First I will show the code behind, then MVVM ( same xaml ). I want to use MVVM and not code behind.

Code Behind (works):

```
var loadOp = ctx.Load<GateBlox.Web.Models.Structure>(ctx.GetStructuresQuery());
        loadOp.Completed += (s, e) => { _treeView.ItemsSource = loadOp.Entities.Where(struc => !struc.StructureParentFK.HasValue); };
```

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <sdk:TreeView x:Name='_treeView' DataContext='{StaticResource ViewModel}'>
        <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource='{Binding Children}'>
                <TextBlock Text='{Binding StructureName}' />
            </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </sdk:TreeView>
</Grid>
```

MVVM (doesnt bind)

```
private LoadOperation<Structure> _loadStructures;
private StructureContext _structureContext;

private IEnumerable<Structure> _structures;
public IEnumerable<Structure> Structures
{
   get { return this._structures; }
   set { this._structures = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Structures"); }
}

public StructuresViewModel()
{
 if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
  {
      _structureContext = new StructureContext();

      _loadStructures = _structureContext.Load(_structureContext.GetStructuresQuery().Where (p=> !  p.StructureParentFK.HasValue));
  _loadStructures.Completed += new EventHandler(_loadStructures_Completed);
   }
}

void _loadStructures_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 this.Structures = _loadStructures.Entities;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the `ItemsSource` for your `TreeView`. I think your xaml should look something like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <sdk:TreeView x:Name='_treeView' DataContext='{StaticResource ViewModel}'
                ItemsSource="{Binding Structures}">
    <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource='{Binding Children}'>
         <TextBlock Text='{Binding StructureName}' />
      </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
  </sdk:TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Abdoul - your code worked although I must say I have no idea why. My Structure table is self referencing - will this XAML bind to grandchildren?

Comment: you code didn't work because you didn't specify what the ItemsSource of your `TreeView` was. There is no place in your code were you specified that the TreeView should show the "Structures".I just added that (`ItemsSource="{Binding Structures}"`).

Comment: Ok - but if you look at my second posting, I did specify the ItemSource for the tree view and the result was that the tree view didnt show the children.

Comment: @greg: in that posting, you specify the `ItemsSource` in the `DataTemplate` of the **nodes** of the tree not the **tree itself**.

Comment: Actually, the ItemSource is specified in both the treeview AND the HierachicalDataTemplate in that posting. Can you suggest the XAML I should use with my self referencing table? - thanks for all your help :-)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "self referencing"?

Answer (score 1):

Have your checked that you are not getting a binding expression error in the output? You are binding the items source of the data template to a property named *Children*, but your view model exposes a data source named **Structures**.

Also, in your working example, you are setting the ItemsSource of the TreeView, but in your MVVM XAML you are setting the ItemsSource of your data template. Is there an inconsistency between what ItemsSource you need to set/bind to?

You might also consider using a collection data source that implements the [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) interface ([ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) or expose the binding source as a [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) that uses a [PagedCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)).

I recommend you take a look at this information about [data binding in MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx#sec6), as it provides excellent guidance on setting up data sources in your view models.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Structures model comes from a DB table that has a self join (like the Northwind employees table.) The example I copied uses code behind and uses the many side of the entity's navigation property and that works, so I left in my references the many side of the join (children). In the MVVM example, I tried binding to Structures instead of Children but that didnt work. I also tried using an Observable collection instead of IEnumerable but no joy.

Comment: Also, I have checked that the data is definitely coming back to the viewmodel, so the problem must be in the XAML.

Comment: Can you show how you are setting up your static resource? At this point, I wonder if the issue is in your DataContext. Have you checked the debug output to verify you are not receiving any binding errors? If you get a breakpoint in the getter of your data source, are you hitting it? (e.g. the XAML binding is attempting to retrieve data).

Comment: First thing you need to do is turn up debug messages for databinding: http://i.imgur.com/UAxJO.png Next, re-run and check the output window and see what errors are there.

Comment: <UserControl.Resources>
        <viewmodel:StructuresViewModel x:Key='ViewModel'></viewmodel:StructuresViewModel></UserControl.Resources>

Comment: NO errors shown in the debug window. Checked settings as per your jpg

Comment: Updated my answer, I just noticed that in your code-behind you are setting the ItemsSource of the TreeView but in the MVVM example you are setting the ItemsSource of the data template. Have you tried a simple test of a plain TreeView with its ItemsSource bound to your Structures property?

Answer (score 0):

I almost have it working now. I took a different approach and went with a HeirarchicalDataTemplate. At the moment the data is showing but not correctly: The child1 record is shwoing up as a parent as well.
    Parent1(level1)
    Parent2(level1)
       Child1(level2)
    Child1(level1)

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="GateBlox.Views.Structure"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
             d:DesignWidth="640"
             d:DesignHeight="480"
             Title="Structure Page"
             xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:GateBlox.ViewModels">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewmodel:StructuresViewModel x:Key='ViewModel'>
    </viewmodel:StructuresViewModel>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      DataContext='{StaticResource ViewModel}'>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Parent}">
            <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic"
                       Text="{Binding Path=StructureName}" />
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}"
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StructureName}"
                       FontWeight="Bold" />
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <sdk:TreeView x:Name='treeView'
                  Width='400'
                  Height='300'
                  ItemsSource='{Binding Structures}'
                  ItemTemplate='{StaticResource NameTemplate}'>
    </sdk:TreeView>
</Grid>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using GateBlox.Web.Models;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;
using GateBlox.Web.Services;
using GateBlox.Helpers;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace GateBlox.ViewModels
{
public class StructuresViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private LoadOperation<Structure> _loadStructures;
    private StructureContext _structureContext;


    private ObservableCollection<Structure> _structures;
    public ObservableCollection<Structure> Structures
    {
        get { return this._structures; }
        set { this._structures = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Structures"); }
    }

    public StructuresViewModel()
    {
        if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
        {
            _structureContext = new StructureContext();

            _loadStructures = _structureContext.Load(_structureContext.GetStructuresQuery());
            _loadStructures.Completed += new EventHandler(_loadStructures_Completed);
        }
    }

    void _loadStructures_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Structures = IEnumerableConverter.ToObservableCollection(_loadStructures.Entities);
    }
}
```

}